# Cascading C++ Templates Usage

Tags: c++, templates

I have two classes:

1. ValueRange
2. MenuItem

A third class Menu uses the MenuItem class to define several menu items, each having a range of values (ints, floats, boolean).

What I did is:

```
template <class T>
class ValueRange{
    private:
        T minValue;
        T maxValue;         
    public:
        void setMinValue(T minValue){this->minValue=minValue;};
        void setMaxValue(T maxValue){this->maxValue=maxValue;};
        ValueRange(){};
        ~ValueRange(){};
};
```

and

```
#include <string>
#include "ValueRange.hh"
class MenuItem{
    private:
      std::string name;
      /*
       * does not compile...
       * error: invalid use of template-name 'ValueRange' 
       * without an argument list
       * error: 'ValueRange' is not a type
       */
      ValueRange value;
    public:
      /*
       * does not compile...
       * error: 'class MenuItem' has no member named 'value' 
       */
      void setValueRange(ValueRange value){this->value=value;}
      MenuItem(){};
      ~MenuItem(){};
};
```

How may I implement the *class MenuItem* that its attribute value is generic, so that I could have menuItems having value ranges of ints, floats, booleans, etc.?

Comment: An abstract base class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class templates in C++ require an instantiation. For example:

```
ValueRange<int>
```

is a valid type.

```
ValueRange
```

without a type is not.

To implement a generic MenuItem, you can for example make MenuItem a templated class as well, or you can make your ValueRange extend a non-templated base class, for example:

```
class ValueRangeBase { /* some virtual members here... */ };

template <class T>
class ValueRange : public ValueRangeBase { /* same as before */ };
```

Then you can use the ValueRangeBase (not by value though) as a generic ValueRange. This is useful some times, but maybe not exactly what you want.

Comment: Looking at the title ("Cascading..."), `ValueRangeBase` is probably what the poster wanted.

Comment: Of course, `ValueRange` is not a template class, but a class template. This may sound pedantic, but the point is exactly that it is *not* a class, but a template. A template from which classes can be generated, like `ValueRange<int>` or `ValueRange<float>`. Getting the terminology straight is a big step of not making errors like the one in the question: Since `ValueRange` is no class (not even a template class), it cannot be used as type. But since it is a template, it can be instantiated, and because it is a *class* template, the instantiations are classes, which can be used as types.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification! It most certainly makes everything clearer. Changing in answer as well!

Comment: I also just notice that you almost certainly wanted to add a type in the sentence "ValueRange is a valid type …".

Answer (score 2):

Just parametrize `MenuItem` the same as `ValueRange`:

```
template<class T>
class MenuItem
{
   ...
   ValueRange<T> value;
   ...
   void setValueRange(ValueRange<T> value) { ... }
   ...
};
```